# Setting Selected value of Select List

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've got this code for the select

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="drpState"
 data-ng-model="vm.complainant.mState"
 data-ng-options="state.abbreviation for state in vm.states track by vm.complainant.mState">
```

I've tried a couple different ways that I've seen through SO, but none seem to be setting the option in the drop down. there are 50 options, it should select the one that is currently in vm.complainant.mState.

I'm grabbing an array of State's from a RESTful API. The state abbreviations show up just fine. But one should be selected by my vm.complainant model. Which is another object that was gotten from the API, which is populated correctly. the complainant has a pState property, lets say it comes back as MN, but for whatever reason I cannot set the selected value of that dropdown either through Jquery or through the model.

when I change the value, it updates the complainant.mState property like it is supposed to when bound to the model. but why is it I cannot select a value?

Comment: `vm.complainant.mState = "MN";` should set the value.

Comment: I'm trying to get the select to set the selected value of the current mState. when the form loads vm.complainant.mState="MN" already. But it doesnt select it in the select control ,its blank, where it should select MN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `state.abbreviation as` at the beginning of your options.

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="drpState"
 data-ng-model="vm.complainant.mState"
 data-ng-options="state.abbreviation as state.abbreviation for state in vm.states">
```

Without the "as" statement you are binding the full object as the value.

This is common for times like `item.id as item.description for item in vm.items` which would bind the id to your model, but show the description in the dropdown.

**Update:** After seeing Dylan's comment I tried out a plunker and removing the Track By fixed the issue.  See [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/igyEbp?p=preview)

Comment: I've tried this. what happens is it now automatically selects the last state in the drop down, "WY" and when changing, it doesn't update vm.complainant.mState for whatever reason. I have no idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Dylan I haven't investigated the Track By clause fully to know why, but removing it seemed to prevent the last item from being selected.

Comment: @Dylan, did removing the track by solve the issue for you like it did for me?  The plunkr has an example of the dropdown working and being pre-set to an initial value.  Check out the plunkr.